# Create a relationship between two entities in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, one-to-many

I have a simple has many relationship between 2 entities in Core Data:

> Team <------->> Games

When I insert a new game managed object into a context, I need to query some properties of the team entity, at the model layer. However, when I use `awakeFromInsert` the relationship has not been set yet, so `team` is `nil`.

```
// game.m
- awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];

    if ([self team] isActive] {
        //.... set game properties
    }
}
```

Is there a way to build the relationship before calling insert and setting the relationship after:

```
Game *newGame = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Game" 
                                            inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[newGame setTeam:team];
```

In rails I would use `@team.games.build` but this doesn't seem possible in Core Data.

Comment: What about `team` here? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand "some properties of the team relationship".  The relationship is just a pointer that you set with `[newGame setTeam:team];`.  Do you mean the `team` entity?

Comment: Could you provide more info about `team`? How do you use `team` in your code snippet? Where do you use the above code? Thanks.

Comment: I added some more. I really need to access the relationship at the model layer at insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you will either need a custom method such as `+ (Game *)insertGameForTeam:(Team *)team` and do your `team` checks there or else handle the relationship conditions in `- (void)willSave` if you need to keep it at the model level.

Using only the default logic, the object doesn't exist until you finish inserting it and you can't associate it with another object until it exists.